# I solved this by mean value theorem and I'm asking am i right

Tags: calculus

[image]

Can I solve case $2$ by same way like that if $b>a$  for the interval $[b,a]$ ?

Comment: Can you just write in what you did here? The image you posted isn't even upright. Also, it is rather unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof is right. It was the mean value theorem indeed. Next time, write your question instead of posting a picture ;-)

Comment: Oh Thank you  and next time i will right them